# android colorize custom button

Tags: android, button

I've created a custom buttom with a selector:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_np"
            android:state_enabled="false"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_np_pressed"
            android:state_pressed="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_np"
            android:state_focused="true"/>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_np"/>
    </selector>
```

I would like to be able to colorize this button by using a gray button as image and then colorize it with a color I've defined.

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sure is possible (at least in code), you set a color filter.

```
import android.graphics.PorterDuff;

Button.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF00FF00,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);  //  Green
Button.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFFFF0000,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);  // Red
```

Just choose your colors and put them in the setColorFilter parameters.

Answer (score 0):

yes it works very well, i use it in mine, simply create a [9Patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html) button and put the name of the image in where you have "@drawable/button_np" the "button_pn" is the name of your button image